# Not really a coding question, its about where "offline data" is stored on an android app and how to access it

Tags: android

I play sports and our team uses the app "hudl" to upload recorded game film. I want to download playlists but I do not have permission to as I am not a coach or team admin. No, I'm not going to ask them. No, I'm not going to sign into one of their accounts. No, I don't feel like screen recording hours and hours worth of film. On the hudl mobile app I am able to click "offline download" film so I can watch it without having internet. It was like a 225 mb download or something. How can I access this downloaded film? No, I can't find it in my files or gallery. It's like saved into the app or some shit. Is there a way to pull this film from the app if it is stored locally in it? I am dumb and need people who know how this works. Sorry for asking an irrelevant question, though this is the first site I thought of to help me.

Answer (score 0):

some apps save big file like video in internal storage. or external storage u can check the folder with (name of apps)  if u not find on there. try check in Android -> Data

but most of them encrypt the file so can only open via apps only.

Comment: Thank you Rofie! I found the data in android -> data -> com.hudl.hudroid, it is not encrypted and displays every .mp4 file and a .jpeg image of the video's thumbail. I'm guessing this is a work around for users to gain access to video downloads if the permissions are set for you not to be able to. Thanks again.